# Enter Key to validate the answer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created an input box and it gets validated by tab key. But it needs to be validated when the enter button is to be pressed.

```js
function checktxt(h, v, w, c) {
  var th = $("#" + h).val();
  var tv = $("#" + v).val();
  if (th.toLowerCase() == tv.toLowerCase()) {
    $("." + c).show();
    $("." + w).hide();
    var win = new Audio('audio/wright.mp3');
  } else if (tv.toLowerCase() == "") {

  } else {
    $("." + c).hide();
    $("." + w).show();
    //setTimeout(function() {  $( "."+w ).hide(); }, 5000); 
    var win = new Audio('audio/wrong.mp3');
  }
  win.play();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position:absolute; margin-left:350px;top:226px;">
  <input id="texthidden1" type="hidden" value="413" />
  <input id="textvisible1" type="text" value="" style="font-size:32px;text-align:center;border:0px solid black;height:50px;width:100px;" maxlength="4" onblur="javascript:checktxt('texthidden1','textvisible1','wrong1','correct1');" />
  <div class="wrong1" style="margin-left: 120px;margin-top: -30px; position:absolute; float:left; display: none; margin-bottom:-30px; ">
    <img src="../images/smallwrong.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="correct1" style="position:absolute;margin-left: 120px; margin-top: -30px; float:left; display: none; margin-bottom:-30px;">
    <img src="../images/smallgreen.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add a keypress handler and check if the key pressed was the enter button, then call your `checktxt` function from there.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform the validation when you detect the enter key is pressed.

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
    // enter pressed now validate
    checktxt(h,v,w,c)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Enter inside input type

```
$("#textvisible1").on('keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        // your code here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Advisable to use saperate function for *enter* keypress and tab.

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return runScript(event)" onblur="javascript:checktxt('texthidden1','textvisible1','wrong1','correct1');" />
```

javascript

```
function runScript(e) {
   var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
   if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
      //call checktxt from here
   }
}
```